# How to add Lexmark E210 to windows 10?

Tags: windows, lexmark-printer

I just got windows 10 and it found my lexmark printer E210 but has it under other devices. I can't get to find it as a printer. I have removed and tried again but same thing. How do I install it manually under printers?

Answer (score 1):

Although the Lexmark E210 does not seem to be supported on windows 10 or on any
64-bit version of Windows, the following
[post](https://www.vistax64.com/threads/lexmark-e210-samsung-ml-1210.268205/)
might have a workaround:

> I have the same Lexmark E210 with Windows 7 64 bit and the same issue. Mine works now.
>   Install the Samsung ML-1200 driver from Samsung site.
>   It will say to turn on your printer and it wont find it but go ahead and install it.
>   Then go into Devices and Printer and you should see the Samsung printer. Right click on it and choose printer properties > Ports tab and make sure the correct USB or correct port is specified. Then print a test page.

The Samsung ML-1200 has a driver for Windows 10, available from the page of
[Samsung ML-1200 Printer Driver for Windows](https://www.samsungprinterdriver.com/2018/05/samsung-ml-1200-printer-driver-windows.html),
with a direct [download link](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software13/printers/SS/SL-M3370FD/SamsungUniversalPrintDriver3PS.exe).

Comment: The Samsung ML driver works with Windows 10

Answer (score -1):

According to the Lexmark compatibility list it would appear your printer is no longer supported and will not work with Windows 10.

http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=EN&page=content&userlocale=EN_US&id=OS28#not_listed

Comment: The Samsung ML-1200 driver enables my Windows 10 box to print to the E210.