# How to add Lexmark E120 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, printing, printer, lexmark-printer

I'm trying to install Lexmark E120 printer on Windows 10, but unfortunately without success. I'm getting "Driver is unavailable" error message in Printers & scanners. I was checking Lexmark website and support for this printer is over.

I was trying to follow [How to add Lexmark E210 to windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1386856/how-to-add-lexmark-e210-to-windows-10) post, but without success. I cannot complete installation, because the printer is not found, and I'm unable to complete the process. Any ideas how I can install this printer?

Here are print screens from installation process:

I can choose New printer, existing printer, and no printer connection.

[image]

Choosing New printer, I cannot go past this screen:

[image]

With existing printer I cannot go past this screen:

[image]

With No printer connection, I can install drivers, but I cannot print anything. If I want to print a document:

[image]

It will tell me to save file as a Printer Files *.prn and it will not print it:

[image]

[image]

I can see it in Device manager, but there are almost no properties to change:

[image]

In printers and scanners I see now both:

[image]

Comment: The answer in that link said " It will say to turn on your printer and it wont find it but go ahead and install it. " Exactly where does the samsung driver fail installing?

Comment: Hi @Moab I added extra print screens with the whole process to my question.

Comment: Select "no printer connection" in the first screenshot.

Comment: Yeah, I did that and printer is there, but I cannot print anything. Print screens are also there in my description.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after quite a bit of effort I was able to get the printer to work in Windows 10 by doing the following:

1. Download the Universal Print Drivers from Lexmark:
   https://downloads.lexmark.com/downloads/drivers/Lexmark_Universal_v2_UD1_Installation_Package_07062021.exe
2. Select the XL driver. I was going to connect the printer via USB and therefore selected the option that the printer would be connected via USB.
3. Connect the printer (via USB) and scan for new printers in Windows. The printer should be found and will be able to print.

Comment: Unfortunately I've got the same results as above. Printer with information that driver is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

This driver worked for me:
https://www.downloaddelivery.com/downloads/pssd/Lexmark_ABB_Vista_X64_HBP_en.exe

Install it as in steps
[image]

Install it in `c:\lexmark\Drivers\sysHBP`

[image]
Click

> The printed that I want isn't listed

[image]

Then continue as in Screenshots
[image]

[image]

[image]

Then provide path
`c:\lexmark\Drivers\sysHBP`